# How to do Migration Postgresql version 13 to postgresql Version 15?

Tags: postgresql

I have already A & B server with streaming replication running with RHEL 7 & Postgresql Version 13.

Now currently planning to upgrade same time like as below-

RHEL version 7 to RHEL 8 along with Postgresql Version 13 to Postgresql version 15  if so..

What would be the best practise and steps to the migration with minimal downtime.

Note : I cannot afford to build new systems and do all the tests as it would be cost affect so.

Hence can some one tel Me what would be the best steps to resolve and apps compatibility is fine in this case.

Thanks for your help in advance.

I haven't yet tried because need to understand different possible solutions so.

Comment: Anyone able to view on My question... Let Me know if any other clarification?